# Finding Two Consecutive Dates

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Hi I have a table "EMP_LEAVE" with some records as below

```
Employee | Leave_Start_Date | Leave_End_Date
1          22-09-2014           26-09-2014
1          29-09-2014           03-10-2014
1          15-12-2014           19-12-2014
1          22-12-2014           24-12-2014
2          07-01-2014           10-01-2014
2          13-01-2014           17-01-2014
2          20-01-2014           24-01-2014
3          10-02-2014           13-02-2014
3          17-02-2014           21-02-2014
```

I want to write a SQL query to find:

1. Employee who has taken leaves more than or equal to "Two Consecutive" weeks or I should say Two weeks in a row?
2. If Yes then whats there Leave_Start_Date and Leave_End_Date for those total leaves?

Any help or direction will be appreciated.

Comment: My Apologies for the format, But I am new member her and cannot post a picture.

Comment: You need to add the query you have tried so far.

Comment: There is no query, Its a table where this data is sitting, I just dont know how to get the desired result

Comment: You need to show some effort to solve the problem. This is not a query writing service.

Comment: Dude, this is complicated...I can find out the Days or hours etc for each entries, But I dont know how to determine if some of these entries are with consecutive dates. Its a tricky one and therefore i asked help.

Comment: I know its not a query writing service, But I am sure someone here should be able to give directions. Not everyone is a born developer...cheers

Comment: Are you looking for separate entries where `Leave_Start_Date` equals another entry's `Leave_End_Date`? Or are the entries for M-F and you're looking for entries for consecutive weeks?

Comment: The second one, I am looking for entries with consecutive weeks.

Comment: So the dates won't line up exactly, they skip weekends. Roger.

Comment: yes, and thats my problem...Even the employee applies leave for whole two weeks, the program is storing the entries separately and now when I have to determine who has taken leaves more than two weeks, I am stuck :(

Comment: it will be useful if you have a 'calendar' table that has a list of days and week numbers for the year. It will make it easier to check for whole weeks and consecutive weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some simple query as below.

```html
select employee,
 Leave_start_date,
 Leave_end_date
from emp_leave
where datediff(Leave_start_date, Leave_end_date) >= 15
```

This query will give you the employees which have taken leave for more than 15 days.

Thanks,
Sarat